# should karma stop watching when test fails

Tags: karma-runner

I have `karma` setup to watch test files. Whenever I change the test is run and I get the following as an output:

```
Chrome 39.0.2171 (Windows 7): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.055 secs / 0.053 secs)
```

However, if I change a test file so that test fails and I get the following output:

```
Chrome 39.0.2171 (Windows 7): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.002 secs / 0 secs)
```

Karma seems to stop watching my files because when I change the file back to the version where test succeeds there is no output when I save my file. Is this an expected behavior?

Comment: It is working for me using PhantomJS. I get the following output but the watch keep on running `PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux): Executed 3 of 3 (1 FAILED) (0.054 secs / 0.024 secs)`.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I thing I know what could be happening. You have the `watch` task after the `karma` task on your Gruntfile.

```
grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'concurrent:test',
    'connect:test',
    'karma',
    'watch:jsTest'
  ]);
```

If the karma task fails then watch won't get called. If it success, watch will have the opportunity to run after that.

```
grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'concurrent:test',
    'connect:test',
    'watch:jsTest',
    'karma'
  ]);
```

Here, you ensure that watch will keep running even if later the karma task fails.

Comment: @Maximus do you have the opportunity to test it by now? I know it's been months since the ask date :-)

Comment: Thanks, actually I've decided not to watch files because it's not really convenient, but maybe when I have the opportunity I'll test your solution.